# Programmatically provision a new Managed Metadata Service Application

Tags: 2010, 2013, sharepoint-server

What is the class available in SharePoint API to programmatically provision a new Managed Metadata service Application or How to provision a new Managed Metadata service application Programmatically using c#

Answer (score 1):

The below code, [from here](http://blog.robgarrett.com/2011/04/14/programmatically-provision-term-store/), is the closest code I have seen to provision in C#, but it is missing crucial parts it feels:

```
private void ProvisionMetadataService()
    {
        // We don't have the metadata service configured, so let's do that.
        var proxy = SPFarm.Local.ServiceProxies.Where(s => s.GetType().Name.Equals("MetadataWebServiceProxy")).FirstOrDefault();
        if (null == proxy)
        throw new SPException("Failed to get instance of metadata web service proxy, is it installed?");
        foreach (var proxyApp in proxy.ApplicationProxies.Where(proxyApp =>
             proxyApp.Properties.ContainsKey("IsDefaultSiteCollectionTaxonomy")))
        {
            proxyApp.Properties["IsDefaultSiteCollectionTaxonomy"] = true;
            proxyApp.Update(true);
        }
        // Give the current user access rights to the metadata service.
        var service = SPFarm.Local.Services.Where(s => s.GetType().Name.Equals("MetadataWebService")).FirstOrDefault();
        if (null == service)
             throw new SPException("Failed to get instance of metadata web service, is it installed?");
        var serviceApp = service.Applications.OfType<SPIisWebServiceApplication>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (null == serviceApp)
             throw new SPException("Failed to get instance of metadata web service app, is it installed?");
        var security = serviceApp.GetAdministrationAccessControl();
        var cba = SPClaimProviderManager.Local;
        var claim = cba.ConvertIdentifierToClaim("DOMAIN\user",SPIdentifierTypes.WindowsSamAccountName);
        security.AddAccessRule(new SPAclAccessRule<SPCentralAdministrationRights>(claim, SPCentralAdministrationRights.FullControl));
        serviceApp.SetAdministrationAccessControl(security);
        serviceApp.Uncache();
        service.Uncache();
    }
```

I usually use PowerShell instead, [code from here](http://www.theroks.com/create-managed-metadata-service-application-with-powershell/):

```
# Loading Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
$snapin = Get-PSSnapin | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell'}
if ($snapin -eq $null) {
   Write-Host "Loading SharePoint Powershell Snapin"
   Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell"
}

$ManagedAccount = Get-SPManagedAccount | select -First 1
if ($ManagedAccount -eq $null) { throw "No Managed Account" }

$ApplicationPool = Get-SPServiceApplicationPool "SharePoint Hosted Services" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if ($ApplicationPool -eq $null)
{
   $ApplicationPool = New-SPServiceApplicationPool "SharePoint Hosted Services" -Account $ManagedAccount
   if (-not $?) { throw "Failed to create an application pool" }
}

Write-Progress "Creating Taxonomy Service Application" -Status "Please Wait..."

$MetadataseviceInstance = (Get-SPServiceInstance |?{$_.TypeName -eq "Managed Metadata Web Service"})
if (-not $?) { throw "Failed to find Metadata service instance" }

if ($MetadataseviceInstance.Status -eq "Disabled")
{
   $MetadataseviceInstance | Start-SPServiceInstance
   if (-not $?) { throw "Failed to start Metadata service instance" }
}

while (-not ($MetadataseviceInstance.Status -eq "Online"))
{
   Write-Host "Waiting for provisioning ..."; sleep 5;
}

$MetaDataServiceApp = New-SPMetadataServiceApplication -Name "Demo Metadata Service Application" -ApplicationPool $ApplicationPool
if (-not $?) {throw "Failed to create Metadata Service Application" }

$MetadataServiceAppProxy = New-SPMetadataServiceApplicationProxy -Name "Demo Metadata Service Application Proxy" -ServiceApplication $MetaDataServiceApp -DefaultProxyGroup

# This service application is the default storage location for Keywords.
$MetadataServiceAppProxy.Properties["IsDefaultKeywordTaxonomy"] = $false

# This service application is the default storage location for column specific term sets.
$MetadataServiceAppProxy.Properties["IsDefaultSiteCollectionTaxonomy"] = $false

# Consumes content types from the Content Type Gallery
$MetadataServiceAppProxy.Properties["IsNPContentTypeSyndicationEnabled"] = $false

# Push-down Content Type Publishing updates from the Content Type Gallery
# to sub-sites and lists using the content type.
$MetadataServiceAppProxy.Properties["IsContentTypePushdownEnabled"] = $false

$MetadataServiceAppProxy.Update()
```

Comment: We use New-SPMetadataServiceApplication in powershell..what is the nearest method in Sharepoint API if available??

Comment: There is not, as I just wrote. The first snippet above is the closest for C#, and as you can see it is already counting on a proxy

Comment: It is counting on proxy, but what if the actual ManagedmetaData service is not set up?? I mean it is not yer configured. We have to provide an application Pool, Database server,Database Name and those are missing.

Comment: Yepp, I do not think you can do that with C#

Comment: Creating an web application,we have the WebApplicationBuilderclass.., In the same way there should be a way to create service applications using Sharepoint APi

Comment: You would think so, but I have never seen a single snippet where someone actually has done that, but I should start looking in to the Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.dll in for example ILSpy and se if you can not find some goodies ;)

Comment: Hey Robert, Creating SiteCollections, Libraries, and adding,Updating items all these are possible using sharepoint API and C#., but desperately looking for the way to provision all the available service applications, Especially SearchService,Metadata and userProfile which are used most..

Comment: Please UPDATE the Thread if you find someway to do so..

Comment: I will, but I do not know a way as of now. I would be happy to see if another user knows though!